# compute the number of subset of {1,2,3,4}

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

How many triple $(A,B,C)$ of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ satisfy  to the following condition?
$$(A\cap B)\subseteq C \subseteq (A\cup B)$$
I think every element of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ has 4 choice ,or in $A$ or in $B$ or in $C$ or in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that satisfy in condition,but it isn't all of choice because $A$ and $B$ can join .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see the following image:

[image]

Now in order to find any sets $A,B,C$ you just need to distribute $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ elements in the six regions! which means that you have to correspond to every element a region in which it belong this makes $6^4$ ways

Comment: how did you draw image?